# Save New Order of Rows in DB of Sortable Table

Tags: php, jquery, mongodb, yii2, jquery-ui-sortable

I've researched a lot of problems like this but I can't seem to find the right solution for me. I am using Yii2 framework in PHP nad MongoDB for my database. I'm also using a [Yii2 sortable extension for GridView](https://github.com/himiklab/yii2-sortable-grid-view-widget) and already installed it in my web application using composer.

Here's my GridView in my **view**:

```
<?php echo SortableGridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    //'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        'code_type',
        'payroll_name',
        'cpf_type',
        [    
            'label' => 'Action',    
            'content' => function ($model, $key, $index, $column) {
                 if ( ($model->company_id != null) && ($model->active == 1) ) {
                    if(in_array($model->payroll_name, array('Basic Salary', 'Overtime Pay', 'Daily/Hourly Wage', 'Commission', 'Bonus', 'Housing Allowance', 'Educational Allowance', 'Travel Allowance', 'Marriage Allowance', 'Leave Encashment', 'Reimbursement'))){
                        return Html::button('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span>', ['value' => Url::to(['view-earnings']).'&id=' . (string)$model->_id, 'class' => 'btn btn-warning btn-view btn-responsive','id' => 'modalButton2']);
                    } else {
                        return Html::button('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span>', ['value' => Url::to(['view-earnings']).'&id=' . (string)$model->_id, 'class' => 'btn btn-warning btn-view btn-responsive','id' => 'modalButton2'])
                        .'&nbsp'
                        . Html::button('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>', ['value' => Url::to(['update-earnings']).'&id=' . (string)$model->_id, 'class' => 'btn btn-success btn-view btn-responsive','id' => 'modalButton3'])
                        .'&nbsp'
                        . Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>', ['delete-earnings', 'id' => (string)$model->_id], ['class' => 'btn btn-danger btn-responsive', 'data' => ['confirm' => 'Are you sure you want to delete this earnings item?', 'method' => 'post']])
                        .'&nbsp'
                        . Html::button('Unset as Default', ['value' => (string)$model->_id, 'class' => 'btn btn-danger btn-responsive', 'onclick'=>'unset(value)']);
                    }
                } else { 
                    return Html::button('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span>', ['value' => Url::to(['view-earnings']).'&id=' . (string)$model->_id, 'class' => 'btn btn-warning btn-view btn-responsive','id' => 'modalButton2'])
                    .'&nbsp'
                    . Html::button('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>', ['value' => Url::to(['update-earnings']).'&id=' . (string)$model->_id, 'class' => 'btn btn-success btn-view btn-responsive','id' => 'modalButton3'])
                    .'&nbsp'
                    . Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>', ['delete-earnings', 'id' => (string)$model->_id], ['class' => 'btn btn-danger btn-responsive', 'data' => ['confirm' => 'Are you sure you want to delete this earnings item?', 'method' => 'post']])
                    .'&nbsp'
                    . Html::button('Set as Default', ['value' => (string)$model->_id, 'class' => 'btn btn-info btn-responsive', 'onclick'=>'set(value)']);
                }
            }
        ]
    ],   
    'sortableAction' => Yii::$app->request->baseUrl . '/index.php?r=payroll-items/earnings-index'
]); ?>
```

**Model:**

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'sort' => [
            'class' => SortableGridBehavior::className(),
            'sortableAttribute' => 'sortOrder'
        ],
    ];
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public function actions()
{
    return [
        'sort' => [
            'class' => SortableGridAction::className(),
            'modelName' => PayrollItems::className(),
        ],
    ];
}
```

I found this [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10641807/how-do-i-save-jquery-ui-sortable-table-positions-to-mysql-database) but I don't know what to put inside `updateworkshops.php` (see top answer) since I am using MongoDB and not MySQL.

As in my current progress, I can only drag my GridView rows but the new order still can't be saved in my database.

Can somebody please explain to me how to do this?

Comment: It seems it is hard coded to use transactional DBs https://github.com/himiklab/yii2-sortable-grid-view-widget/blob/master/SortableGridBehavior.php#L58

Comment: You can always extend `SortableGridBehavior`, implementing your own `gridSort` and `beforeInsert` methods that work correctly with MongoDB.